# Firebase realtime database only owner can edit the post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is how my firebase database looks like:

[image]

I am using firebase realtime database. At the moment all users can create a post which is good. All users can delete their post if they are the owner (which is what i want), when a user is editing a post that he does not own, it creates a duplicate of that post with the new updated information.

They are not editing the original post they are duplicating it under their uid.
What are the rules so they can't duplicate the post?

those are my rules:

```
   {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "posts":{
        "$uid":{
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

this is my code

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
        userRef.on("value", (snapShot) => {
          setCurrentUser({ key: snapShot.key, ...snapShot.val() });
        });
      }
      if (setCurrentUser(userAuth)) {
      } else if (!userAuth && typeof window !== "undefined") {
        return null;
      }

      const uid = userAuth.uid;
      console.log(uid);
      setId(uid);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const postKey = props.farm.postKey;
  console.log(id);

  const DeletePost = () => {
    getFirebase()
      .database()
      .ref(`Users/Posts/`)
      .child(`${id}`)
      .child(`${postKey}`)
      .remove();
  };

  

    const updatePost = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const obj = {
        ...values,
      };
      const postKey = props.farm.postKey;
      getFirebase()
        .database()
        .ref(`Users/Posts/`)
        .child(`${id}`)
        .child(`${postKey}`)
        .update(obj, (err) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        });
    };
```

Comment: It's hard to reason about security rules without seeing the code that exercises them. Can you edit your question to include the code that you want to be allowed, and the code that you want to be rejected by the rules?

Comment: I have added my code to the post

Comment: Do you want other users to have the permission to edit posts that are not belong to them?

Comment: no. i want only users that own the post to be able to edit the post. As it is right now users can't edit the original post, but when they try to edit it it creates another post under their id, but with the updated information.

Comment: when i render the posts i see both the original post from the original owner and the updated post from the person who did not own the post